# How can I download testNG code (not the plug in)

Tags: testng, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to download the code for this

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.arquillian.testng/arquillian-testng-standalone/1.4.1.Final

But can't seem to find it online. Anyone have any suggestions on where to look, who to contact?

Answer (score 0):

Every official arquillian artifact is published with accompanying source code. What you are looking for is [arquillian-testng-standalone-1.4.1.Final-sources.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/arquillian/testng/arquillian-testng-standalone/1.4.1.Final/arquillian-testng-standalone-1.4.1.Final-sources.jar).

But you can equally well just clone [official GitHub repository](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-core). Here's the corresponding tag for this released artifact: https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-core/tree/1.4.1.Final/testng.